# How to fix "TypeError: 'UnboundField' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)]
                           , render_kw={"placeholder": "Please enter username"})

    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=12, max=25)],
                             render_kw={"placeholder": "Enter a password"})

    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    while True:
        if (any(char.islower() for char in password)
                and any(char.isupper() for char in password)
                and any(char.isdigit() for char in password)
                and any(char in punctuation for char in password)):

            print("Password is correct")

        else:
            print("Needs at least 1 upper and lowercase letter and 1 number and special character")
        break

    def validate_username(self, username):
        existing_user_username = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if existing_user_username:
            raise ValidationError(
                print('It seems there are two of you, make another one.'))
```

This is where I think my main problems are. I am trying to have my program check if a password has 1 upper, 1 lower, 1 digit, and 1 special character. But I can not find a way to fix that error. As well as when a username already exists, why it wont print my message to show that the username already exists. I didn't want to flood the thread so here is a github with all my current code I am working with if needed.

https://github.com/FasterJake/Flask-login-regis

Comment: Within my registration form? What do you mean, or is this to have it print in the page that the user exists?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the code to while True:
It's an infinite loop because it's always true

Add the code to validate_password method instead

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=15)]
                           , render_kw={"placeholder": "Please enter username"})

    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=12, max=25)],
                             render_kw={"placeholder": "Enter a password"})

    submit = SubmitField('Register')
    
    def validate_password(form, field):
        password = field.data
        if (any(char.islower() for char in password)
                and any(char.isupper() for char in password)
                and any(char.isdigit() for char in password)
                and any(char in punctuation for char in password)):
            print("Password is correct")
            return True
        else:
            raise ValidationError(print("Needs at least 1 upper and lowercase letter and 1 number and special character"))
            

    def validate_username(self, username):
        existing_user_username = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if existing_user_username:
            raise ValidationError(
                print('It seems there are two of you, make another one.'))
```

Comment: Ya I wasn't sure how to use the data from password to validate, I was looking all over to find a fix for that error. You were the first one to help me out. If you don't mind explaining a bit about why I can't do validate_password(self, password) like validate_username(self, username) that might give me a little more understanding. Don't want to take to much of your time though.

Comment: Hey @fasterjake happy to help :) we all start the same way, also you can use ```validate_password(self, password)``` as well, would be using ```password.data``` then instead of ```field.data```

Comment: Worked out awesome, thank you Kavi I have another question for you. Would this work to have a user update the password? Ill add it into my question.

Comment: @fasterjake yep should work there as well